# Why doesn't the equipartition theorem force the rotational energy of a monoatomic molecule to be significant?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I'm reviewing the Feynman Lectures and in them he states that the rotational kinetic energy of a monoatomic molecule in a gas is insignificant due to a small moment of inertia.

But wouldn't the equipartition theorem simply make it so the angular velocity would be large enough to make up for it? I.e. shouldn't the random collisions eventually dump an equal amount of energy into each degree of rotational motion as in each degree of translational motion?

EDIT:

I'm coming at this purely from a classical POV, so please avoid Quantum Mechanical answers if possible.

Comment: Please edit your question to give a specific reference to a section and page number. I don't think this can be explained properly without quantum mechanics. An atom in a monoatomic gas *can't* rotate due to symmetry, but Feynman may not say that if quantum mechanics hasn't been introduced yet at that point.

Comment: Let's assume we are talking about macroscopic spheres of matter for the sake of argument. 

As a side note, you say monatomic gas's cant rotate due to symmetry - but don't alpha particles have internal structure and thus should be able to be distinguishable by orientation?

Comment: Because the quantum energy levels are spaced far enough that the equipartition theorem (a fact of classical physics) doesn’t hold anymore.

Comment: @knzhou: It's not just that the energy levels may be widely spaced, it's that they essentially don't exist for a monoatomic gas. Single-atom species don't have rotational bands. (In, e.g., monoatomic hydrogen you can generate angular momentum by electronic excitations, but that doesn't give a rotational band.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the fact that some group of molecules has much smaller moment of inertia than the rest does not make the group except from the equipartition theorem.

But there is a physical reason for why sometimes certain regions of phase space or degrees of freedom are discarded as non-contributing to total energy. In other words, there is a reason for why equipartition theorem or equal treatment of all degrees of freedom is not accurate.

This reason is "extremely slow equilibration". Some degrees of freedom are in only a very weak interaction with the rest of the system. For example, collisions of spheres do transfer energy from translational to rotational energy, but only very slowly. If the system achieved temperature by quickly accepting energy from outside, some rotational degrees of freedom may not have enough time to acquire the same temperature as the other degrees of freedom. The more smooth the spheres, the longer the time to equilibrate. If this time is astronomical, for some regions of phase space it makes sense to just exclude them from calculations, because the probability they are realized is extremely small so they do not contribute much.

Another similar example: atmospheric gas in a closed vessel with microscopic hole in the wall through which gas molecules escaping to vacuum with only a slow rate. Because of the hole, the phase space available is infinite, and the equilibrium state is that density is close to zero everywhere. But because the hole is so small, the gas in the vessel achieves temporary quasi equilibrium with itself, with some high temperature and high density. To find properties of the gas, only volume of the vessel is important, not the vast space outside it. Again, a part of the phase space is discarded because it is not relevant in the time period considered.

There are other examples: such as oxygen and hydrogen gases in a cold vessel forming water after a long time, or escape of atmosphere molecules from Earth's gravity field. These processes are so slow they are usually ignored.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question than OP’s. The answer to OP’s question involves quantum effects.

Comment: What would the relaxation time be classically for OPs example? Because if it turns out to be seconds, then this doesn't answer the question, but if it's much longer (how much I'm less sure of) then it does.

Comment: Very interesting... Is there a way to estimate this slow equilibration time? Can you refer me to some resources that discuss this?

Comment: @jacob1729 It seems problematic to evaluate a classical relaxation time given the lack of a classical model of an atom which is stable over a timescale of seconds...

Comment: @DuncanHarris I don't see why that's an issue. The rest of the calculation doesn't rely on knowing the substructure accurately.

Comment: @knzhou please see the edit of the original question.

Comment: @charlysotelo I do not know of any quick and easy way to estimate the time, such topic belongs to physical kinetics and non-equilibrium statistical physics.

Comment: @jacob1729 The substructure seems essential to quantifying the typical transfer of angular momentum between atoms in a collision. Perhaps you are imagining a different way of calculating the relaxation time which does not rely on this quantity? If so I am interested!

Comment: @charlysotelo I found this paper, but cannot access it: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238087475_A_Billiard_Model_for_a_Gas_of_Particles_with_Rotation

Comment: @DuncanHarris I was imagining that the calculation could be done for hard spheres of a given radius. This is close to the 'classical' picture of atoms. As soon as you have quantum mechanics I think it becomes obvious this whole question is not an issue, what's intriguing about this answer is that it offers a classical way out.

Comment: @jacob1729 If your model is hard sphere atoms with a spherically symmetric radial repulsive interaction, then there can be no angular momentum transfer and the relaxation time is infinite.  Is that the model you are talking about?